# If string contains an element of list for a easy chatbot

Tags: python, string, list, chatbot

I'm making a very basic chatbot in Python. I tried using a list of salutations like so: `saludos=['hola','hi','despierta','ola','alo','despertar']`

```
hablar=input("Hablar/acción → ").lower()
if hablar in saludos:
    print("Alice ha despertado.")
    print("hello!")
```

How can I make this work if the input contains an element of list without matching exactly? For instance, if the user writes, hola bot or hi bot how are u, I want it to print back, hola. My code only works if all you write is hola or  ola or hi.

Comment: Try converting all the letters to lower() & then do a compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to compare...

```
saludos=['hola','hi','despierta','ola','alo','despertar']
hablar=input("Hablar/acción → ").lower()
for i in saudos:
    if i in hablar:
       print("Alice ha despertado.")
       print("hello!")
       break
```

Comment: @Darkknight You have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
saludos=['hola','hi','despierta','ola','alo','despertar']

hablar=input("Hablar/acción → ").lower()

for w in saludos:
    if w in hablar:
        print("Alice ha despertado.")
        print("hello!")
```